# How can I display a features of a image that was extracted by a Resnet50 model in keras

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

So what I am trying to do is display the features that were extracted from a Resnet50 model and saved as a .npy.

I can read it in all and fine and the array looks fine. But I cannot figure out a way to display the results well. How can I show this in `matplotlib` of `opencv`?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import cm
import os

path = "ResnetFeatures/"

def load_resnet_features(file, path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
    return np.load(file_path)

test_file = '1500test.npy'




test_feature = load_resnet_features(test_file, path)
print(test_feature.shape)
test_feature = np.squeeze(test_feature, axis=0)
print(test_feature.shape)
test_feature = test_feature.reshape((49, 2048))
plt.imshow(test_feature)
plt.show()
```

Which gives this

```
(1, 7, 7, 2048)
(7, 7, 2048)
```

This gives this, but it is not what I want. I would like something that is more square in shape are the original image is (224,224,3)
[image]

Comment: There is no square that can represent 3 colors with 7*7*2048 values.

Comment: Is there a way to reshape it to be X by X? I think to total features are 10500 something so split that into half and make an image like that?

Comment: you did reshape it with `test_feature.reshape((49, 2048))`.  You could do that with different values, but you would lose the colors.

Comment: I had tried with different values for it

Comment: So the total number of pixels is 100352 I tried to divide it by half and it gave an error like this cannot reshape array of size 100352 into shape (50176, 50176)

Comment: You have to take the square root of it.  (50176, 50176) is 50176 rows and columns, so 2517630976 values

Comment: do you mean take the sqrt of 100352 as that does not do it evenly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out thanks to Jake P help.
[image]

So I know the image can be reshaped like (49, 2048)
So I brock apart 2048 to get this
(7,7) (64, 32) 
Then just cross multipled
(7*32) (7 * 64)

```
test_feature = test_feature.reshape((448, 224))
print_shape(test_feature)
```